# How to make double click event into single click event in angular 4?

Tags: angular, file, events, download

I have click event in span.While clicking the span icon, it downloads the appropriate file.If I click double time, it's downloads two times.Any solution for this.
**Html:**

```
     <ng-template #tmplt>

    <tr *ngFor="let kbase of Colum | paginate: paginationConfig; let i =index">
        <td>{{isEnglish ? kbase.Name :kbase.Name_AR}}</td>
        <td><span class="sprite eye" (click)="download(kbase.DocId)" ></span></td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

**Method:**

```
  download(id: number) {
        if (id != 0) {
            this._documentService.downloadDcoumentDetails(id, 'KnowledgeHub').subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    if (response.content != null) {
                        this.performDownloadFile(response.fileName, response.content);                      
                    }
                }, err => { }, () => {

                });
        }

    }
    performDownloadFile(fileName: string, content: any) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style.display = "none";
        let blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
        let objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = objectUrl;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
    }

Thanks
```

.

Comment: So basically, as long as the download process triggered by the last click isn't completed, any next click should have no side effects? Or if the user clicks N times in a specific time window, only 1 click event should be triggered? Please be a little more specific. And please rephrase the title of your question, is kinda misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the [**Observable's world**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/). Just use Observable to get the desired result. Get the reference of your input in the component and use this code. `debounceTime` will let the event to trigger at least after `1 second` from the previous trigger. It will let you not to fire on every `click` when user double clicks.

```
Observable.fromEvent(yourButton, 'click').debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => /* */)
```

> Select your target button with @viewchild() or something like that

In the `subscribe` method you can write your logic.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean to the function `download(id)` like so:

```
var clicked = false;

function download(id) {
    if(!clicked){
        clicked = true;
        service.get(url).subscribe(function(data){
            clicked = false;
        });
    }
}
```

This will prevent a double click while the current download is still being performed.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a variable to control whether there's a download already running or not.

Something like this:

```
public downloadInProgress = false;

public download(id: string) {
  if (this.downloadInProgress) {
    return;
  }

  this.downloadInProgress = true;
}
```

```

Then, once you receive the file from your API/Server you can assign `false` to this flag.